# NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f09b9f0a7c0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused)

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-rest-framework, document

I am trying to build a simple django elastice search which can search cars. But when I am trying to rebuid the indexes, it gives me the error above. I am following this doc -> [quickstart elasticsearch](https://django-elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#install-and-configure)...full traceback is given below->

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f09b9f0a7c0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused) caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f09b9f0a7c0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused)
```

my models.py is simple Car model having name, color, description, type filds on which I add in document

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    type = models.IntegerField(choices=[
        (1, "Sedan"),
        (2, "Truck"),
        (4, "SUV"),
    ])
```

my documents.py file->

```
from django_elasticsearch_dsl import Document
from django_elasticsearch_dsl.registries import registry
from .models import Car


@registry.register_document
class CarDocument(Document):
    class Index:
        name = 'cars'
        settings = {'number_of_shards': 1,
                    'number_of_replicas': 0}

    class Django:
        model = Car

        fields = [
            'name',
            'color',
            'description',
            'type',
        ]
```

but when i am trying to rebuid the index, it gives the new connection error. The command I am using to rebuild the index is given below ->

```
python manage.py search_index --rebuild
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all make sure you have installed and configured ElasticSearch service properly (you can use this [document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/install-elasticsearch.html)).This error is saying that your code could not connect to `ElasticSearch` service with your current configs. Check if your elastic service is up and running. In Linux based OS you can check it by `$ sudo systemctl status elasticsearch.service` and in the result page you should see the line `Active: active (running)`. After this step check the url `http://localhost:9200/` (if you did not change the default settings) and if everything is OK you should see the following results:

```
{
  "name" : "some_name-System-Product-Name",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "erP_jdhLRvuwqLkx1_tehw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.9.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "deb",
    "build_hash" : "a479a2a7fce0389512d6a9361301708b92dff667",
    "build_date" : "2020-08-11T21:36:48.204330Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.6.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

You can also start this service by using `$ sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service`. Another possibility is that maybe you configured elastic variables in a wrong way. For example instead of default port (i.e. 9200) using wrong port will also raise the same error. In following example you can see an example of Elastic configs which will goes in your project's `settings.py`:

```
# ElasticSearch configs
ELK_BASE_URL = 'elasticsearch://{username}:{password}@{host_ip}:{host_port}'
ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL = ELK_BASE_URL.format(
    username='ELASTICSEARCH_USER',
    password='ELASTICSEARCH_PASS',
    host_ip='ELASTICSEARCH_HOST',
    host_port='ELASTICSEARCH_PORT'
)
ELASTICSEARCH_DSL = {
    'default': {
        'hosts': [ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL]
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error. But I've used ES in docker-containers. So if you will face this error, there is some things that helped me:

Environment variables for *elasticsearch* service in docker-compose.yml file:

```
environment:
   - xpack.security.enabled=false
   - discovery.type=single-node
   - network.host=0.0.0.0
   - http.port=9200
```

You should also try to bring everything(services) under one network in docker-compose.yml
And also in these lines I used service(defined in docker-compose.yml) name:

```
ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL = ELK_BASE_URL.format(
...
host_ip='elasticsearch',
host_port='9200'
```

)

Please, **pay attention** to first line in environment before deploy.